# django_rest_framwork occured "TypeError: 'Link' object does not support item assignment"

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-swagger

A project using Django, DRF, swagger.

url config below:

```
schema_view = get_swagger_view(title='Pastebin API')
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', schema_view),
    url(r'store', include('store.urls')),
    ... # other urls using routers.SimplerRouter
]
```

and store/urls.py:

```
router = routers.SimpleRouter()
router.register(r'', views.StoreViewSet)
urlpatterns = router.urls
```

and views.StoreViewSet:

```
class StoreViewSet(BaseObject, GenericViewSet):
    permition_class = ()

    @list_route()
    def detail(self, request):
        return {}

    @list_route(url_path='detail/export')
    def detail_export(self, request):
        return {}
```

after `python manage.py runserver`, visit `http://127.0.0.1:8000/#` and a TypeError occured:

```
File "/usr/local/share/.virtualenvs/dev-finance/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework_swagger/views.py", line 32, in get
schema = generator.get_schema(request=request)
File "/usr/local/share/.virtualenvs/dev-finance/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/schemas.py", line 242, in get_schema
links = self.get_links(request)
File "/usr/local/share/.virtualenvs/dev-finance/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/schemas.py", line 276, in get_links
insert_into(links, keys, link)
File "/usr/local/share/.virtualenvs/dev-finance/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/schemas.py", line 79, in insert_into
target[keys[-1]] = value
TypeError: 'Link' object does not support item assignment
[ERROR] 2017-05-04 15:25:06,936 log_message(basehttp.py:131) "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 20384
```

The error message shows, the `Link` object can't assign value, like dict does.

If I rename the method name from `detail_export` to `details_export`, everything goes fine again.

Guessing error occured when rest_framework's `@list_route` decorater
 transfer the method's url to Link object.

why other methods just goes fine?
how can I solve this?

Comment: This looks like a name collision to me. It's weird because "detail" method in a DRF viewset is called "retrieve". Does it work without swagger schema generation?

Comment: @Igonato  the name of all methods in viewset are different. It work without swagger.

Comment: As I thought. I'd just go with another name if I were you. Also, in Python there is a convention to add "_" at the end to break name collisions, e.g. `print_ = "Hello world!"; print(print_) `

Answer (score 3):

This is [the bug in DRF](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/4704). Probably, it will be fixed in 3.6.4. Now you can:

1. Delete `url_path` from `list_route`:

   ```
   class StoreViewSet(BaseObject, GenericViewSet):
       permition_class = ()

       @list_route()
       def detail(self, request):
           return {}

       @list_route()
       def detail_export(self, request):
           return {}
   ```
2. Or use a custom `SchemaView` with a custom `SchemaGenerator`:

   ```
   # api/schema.py for example

   from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny
   from rest_framework.renderers import CoreJSONRenderer
   from rest_framework.response import Response
   from rest_framework.schemas import SchemaGenerator
   from rest_framework.views import APIView
   from rest_framework_swagger import renderers


   class CustomSchemaGenerator(SchemaGenerator):
       def get_keys(self, subpath, method, view):
           result = super().get_keys(subpath, method, view)
           # here you can fix your path
           if result == ['store', 'detail', 'detail_export']:  
               return ['store', 'detail_export'] 
           return result


   class SwaggerSchemaView(APIView):
       _ignore_model_permissions = True
       exclude_from_schema = True
       permission_classes = [AllowAny]
       renderer_classes = [
           CoreJSONRenderer,
           renderers.OpenAPIRenderer,
           renderers.SwaggerUIRenderer
       ]

       def get(self, request):
           generator = CustomSchemaGenerator(title='API')
           return Response(generator.get_schema(request=request))

   # urls.py

   from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
   from api.schema import SwaggerSchemaView   

   urlpatterns = [
       # ...
       url(r'^swagger-url/', login_required(SwaggerSchemaView.as_view()))
       # ...
   ]
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hack:

1. Open 
   your-environment-folder/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/schemas.py
2. Find "insert_into" function
3. Replace this:

   ```
   target[keys[-1]] = value
   ```

with this:

```
if type(target) != coreapi.Link:
    target[keys[-1]] = value
```